# nodejs auto maintain winston log

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm trying to integrate winston to a nodeJs Express app. It works but I don't know how could it be auto maintained. I wanted something like when it reach, for example 50000 rows, it delete the first ones before adding the new ones for terms of space. The idea is doing that without something like cron. Is it possible?

Here is my testing code:

```
//Winston logger
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = format;
const winstonFormat = printf(info => {
    return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});
const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    //maxsize:'10000', //It doesn't works for me
    format: combine(
        label({ label: config.environment }),
        timestamp(),
        winstonFormat
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
        new transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
    ]
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.add(new transports.Console({
        format: format.simple()
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for log rotation, so googling "winston log rotation" points to https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file, which is probably just the ticket for you.